# Rails server not started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionpack

I get following error while start `rails server` of previously running rails application.

```
/home/ganesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch.rb:35:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack (LoadEr
ror)
        from /home/ganesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ganesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:3:in `require'
        from /home/ganesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ganesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `require'
        from /home/ganesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

How to remove this error. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

First, What service you are using is also important.

Open a command window and type:

```
irb --simple-prompt
>> require 'rack'
=> true
>>
```

If rack’s not there you will get an error like:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- rack
```

You can install rack by opening a new command window and typing:

```
gem install rack
```

Also check, **Did you try to run the command**

```
rails s
```

from your application folder ?

Comment: Do you have the rack gem installed? bundle exec probably will not help here, it would be a different kind of error.

Comment: I don't know how to install rack gem

Comment: So what service did you use? Do you have `rack` installed? gem 'rack' in a gemfile.

Comment: my rvm version is: rvm 1.17.3

Comment: You need to run "bundle" after adding the "rack" gem into it.

Comment: As you mentioned that the rails app was previously running. So how it stopped now? Probably you are not running from your application folder. Check again.

Comment: when this application was running the electricity went off, and after restart pc and applicaion this error occur

Comment: same application is running in next pc

Comment: then check your rails version, rack version in another pc and see if it matches with current. Do some checks. You are missing any.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23899/discussion-between-gami-and-saurabh-jain)